# Is the reciprocal of a Wiener-process is well defined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Is the reciprocal of a Wiener-process is well defined?

More generally, does Stochastic Calculus work with such „reciprocal processess” of the form $\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)_{t}$, where the denominator can be zero with positive probability? If yes, how are they usually managed?

E.g. the following integral process is „correct”?
$$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{1-t}dB_{t},\;\;\;T\in\left[0,1\right]$$

(I wrote $T\in\left[0,1\right]$ instead of $T\in\left[0,1\right)$ intentionally.)

Comment: If $X$ is normally distributed then $\frac1 X$ is well defined with probability $1$. However, if $(X_t)$ is the Wiener process then  there is no single null set outside which $\frac 1 {X_t}$ is defined for all $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here [Proof that a standard Brownian motion visits zero infinitely often at the beginning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn) and [Zero set of Brownian Motion is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152900/zero-set-of-brownian-motion-is-uncountable) we have

> Let $B_t, t\ge0$ be a standard Brownian motion that starts at 0. Prove that, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
> $$P(\#\{t\in(0,\epsilon]\mid B_t = 0\}=\infty)=1.$$

So given a realization $B_{t}(\omega)$ we have that it keeps hitting zero uncountably many times. This is true for almost every realization.

Usually the way to define reciprocal is via the use of the Bessel process i.e. conditioning the Wiener process to avoid the x-axis.